# NoResourceAvailableException when running WordCount example on Windows

Tags: apache-flink

I managed to bring up Flink 1.17.1 cluster on Windows (from git-bash), but when I tried to run the WordCount example, got NoResourceAvailableException with the default config. I tried to increase memory and task slots, got same exception. Any help would be appreciated.

It works fine out of box on Linux.

The program finished with the following exception:

```
org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The main method caused an error: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 866f9111f86dec98f182a9cb08dc5af9)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:372)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.invokeInteractiveModeForExecution(PackagedProgram.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.client.ClientUtils.executeProgram(ClientUtils.java:105)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.executeProgram(CliFrontend.java:851)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.run(CliFrontend.java:245)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.parseAndRun(CliFrontend.java:1095)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.lambda$mainInternal$9(CliFrontend.java:1189)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.security.contexts.NoOpSecurityContext.runSecured(NoOpSecurityContext.java:28)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.mainInternal(CliFrontend.java:1189)
        at org.apache.flink.client.cli.CliFrontend.main(CliFrontend.java:1157)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 866f9111f86dec98f182a9cb08dc5af9)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.reportGet(CompletableFuture.java:395)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.get(CompletableFuture.java:1999)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.getJobExecutionResult(StreamContextEnvironment.java:171)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.StreamContextEnvironment.execute(StreamContextEnvironment.java:122)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.environment.StreamExecutionEnvironment.execute(StreamExecutionEnvironment.java:2058)
        at org.apache.flink.streaming.examples.wordcount.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:159)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.PackagedProgram.callMainMethod(PackagedProgram.java:355)
        ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: Job failed (JobID: 866f9111f86dec98f182a9cb08dc5af9)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:130)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:642)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.client.program.rest.RestClusterClient.lambda$pollResourceAsync$32(RestClusterClient.java:787)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:2073)
        at org.apache.flink.util.concurrent.FutureUtils.lambda$retryOperationWithDelay$6(FutureUtils.java:302)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniWhenComplete(CompletableFuture.java:859)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniWhenComplete.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:837)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postFire(CompletableFuture.java:610)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniCompose.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:1085)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$Completion.run(CompletableFuture.java:478)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobExecutionException: Job execution failed.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobResult.toJobExecutionResult(JobResult.java:144)
        at org.apache.flink.client.deployment.ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.lambda$null$6(ClusterClientJobClientAdapter.java:128)
        ... 23 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.JobException: Recovery is suppressed by NoRestartBackoffTimeStrategy
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.handleFailure(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:139)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.failover.flip1.ExecutionFailureHandler.getFailureHandlingResult(ExecutionFailureHandler.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.recordTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:258)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.handleTaskFailure(DefaultScheduler.java:249)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultScheduler.onTaskFailed(DefaultScheduler.java:242)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.onTaskExecutionStateUpdate(SchedulerBase.java:748)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.SchedulerBase.updateTaskExecutionState(SchedulerBase.java:725)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.notifyTaskFailure(UpdateSchedulerNgOnInternalFailuresListener.java:51)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.DefaultExecutionGraph.notifySchedulerNgAboutInternalTaskFailure(DefaultExecutionGraph.java:1664)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1140)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.processFail(Execution.java:1080)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.executiongraph.Execution.markFailed(Execution.java:919)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionOperations.markFailed(DefaultExecutionOperations.java:43)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionDeployer.handleTaskDeploymentFailure(DefaultExecutionDeployer.java:327)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionDeployer.lambda$assignAllResourcesAndRegisterProducedPartitions$2(DefaultExecutionDeployer.java:170)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniHandle(CompletableFuture.java:930)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniHandle.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:907)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:506)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeExceptionally(CompletableFuture.java:2088)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.PendingRequest.failRequest(PendingRequest.java:88)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.cancelPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:185)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.failPendingRequests(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:408)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.slotpool.DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(DeclarativeSlotPoolBridge.java:396)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmaster.JobMaster.notifyNotEnoughResourcesAvailable(JobMaster.java:887)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.lambda$handleRpcInvocation$0(AkkaRpcActor.java:301)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.concurrent.akka.ClassLoadingUtils.runWithContextClassLoader(ClassLoadingUtils.java:83)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcInvocation(AkkaRpcActor.java:300)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:222)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.FencedAkkaRpcActor.handleRpcMessage(FencedAkkaRpcActor.java:84)
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.rpc.akka.AkkaRpcActor.handleMessage(AkkaRpcActor.java:168)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:24)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.apply(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:127)
        at scala.PartialFunction.applyOrElse$(PartialFunction.scala:126)
        at akka.japi.pf.UnitCaseStatement.applyOrElse(CaseStatements.scala:20)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:175)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at scala.PartialFunction$OrElse.applyOrElse(PartialFunction.scala:176)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:537)
        at akka.actor.Actor.aroundReceive$(Actor.scala:535)
        at akka.actor.AbstractActor.aroundReceive(AbstractActor.scala:220)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:579)
        at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:547)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:270)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:231)
        at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:243)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:290)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.topLevelExec(ForkJoinPool.java:1020)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.scan(ForkJoinPool.java:1656)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1594)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:183)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
        at org.apache.flink.runtime.scheduler.DefaultExecutionDeployer.lambda$assignResource$4(DefaultExecutionDeployer.java:227)
        ... 40 more
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.CompletionException: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.encodeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:331)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.completeThrowable(CompletableFuture.java:346)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:632)
        ... 38 more
Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.jobmanager.scheduler.NoResourceAvailableException: Could not acquire the minimum required resources.
```

I tried to increase memory and task slots, got same exception. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've often found `NoResourceAvailableException` exceptions to be red-herrings. You may have to look deeper into the task and job manager logs to try and find a more descriptive error. A majority of the time I've seen these, they are totally unrelated to resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that TaskManager fails to start because TaskManager tries to create a working directory with a colon in the name. Windows does not allow colon in file/directory names.